# Authenticating with App Engine in a Sencha mobile app

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, sencha-touch, openid

I have a web app running on app engine that uses google accounts for authentication (OAuth).

Now I'm trying to develop a mobile app using Sencha Touch and I'm stuck with how do I authenticate users with app engine. Loading the login page in the app looks ugly and opening login page in the device's browser is not so bad but I have no idea how to (if at all possible) to retrieve the cookie and store it in the app (so that they don't have to sign in everytime)

Ideally, I want to display a simple sencha form that asks for credentials and then checks that their valid with google. I still have no idea how to handle two factor authentication though.

I'm tempted to write my own authentication procedures and store user credentials manually on the datastore but I feel this shouldn't be that hard..

Has anyone been able to do this? Would openID provide an easier approach for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google App Engine Boilerplate. Their authentication flow is implemented pretty nicely (together with a bunch of other stuffs, like testing :D).
This should give you a head start. I am currently using it together with Sencha Touch
https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate